# Same Query getting different results in Loopback?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, debugging, loopbackjs, loopback

I have querying a database from two different locations.. The query is identical and the values being passed in are identical.  However one query is finding a match, and the other is not.

**This Query returns a result**

```
app.models.OrgProvider.find( {where: { orgId: data.orgId, providertypeId: data.typeID}, include: 'provider' }, function(err, orgprovider){

          //data.providerId = orgprovider[0].toJSON().provider.id;

          console.log('find provider via Create: ' + orgprovider);
          console.log('orgId: ' + data.orgId);
          console.log('providertypeId: ' + data.typeID);

          callback(null, data);
        });
```

outputs to console

```
find provider via Create: [object Object]
orgId: 5a029ead07e76372952b4ca0
providertypeId: 1
```

**This Query returns EMPTY**

```
app.models.OrgProvider.find( {where: { orgId: ticket.orgId, providertypeId: typeID}, include: 'provider' }, function(err, orgprovider){

          //data.providerId = orgprovider[0].toJSON().provider.id;

          console.log('find provider via reAllocate: ' + orgprovider);
          console.log('orgId: ' + ticket.orgId);
          console.log('providertypeId: ' + typeID);

          cb(null,ticket);
        });
```

outputs to console

```
find provider via reAllocate: 
orgId: 5a029ead07e76372952b4ca0
providertypeId: 1
```

Paramaters being passed into the find are identical, and yet one is returning a result and the other isn't

Is there a way I can inspect the query for that is being sent to the Database to determine the difference?  Or any suggestions on why I would be getting different results?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: set profiling level on you mongodb instance to see what your queries are https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can inspect the query for that is being sent to the
>   Database to determine the difference?

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Setting-debug-strings.html

Linux and probably MACOS

`DEBUG=loopback:connector:mongodb node .`

Windows

`set DEBUG=loopback:connector:mongodb`

`node .`

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  Was able to determine that in one query. typeID is passed in as a string and the other passed in as a number.  Thanks again!